# Laravel 5.3 : Can I add a part of the fields of an table to the index of `algolia`？

Tags: laravel, algolia

Can I add a part of the fields of an table to the index of `algolia`？

For example:

There is a table `articles`,it's fileds like this：

`id title content author status created_at updated_at deleted_at`

I only want to add the 4 fileds `id title content author` to the index of `algolia`,

I read the docs of  `Scout` in Laravel `5.3`,it seems not to be mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `toSearchableArray` method on your model.

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
  return [
       'objectID' => $this->id,
       'title' => $this->title,
       'content' => $this->content,
       'author' => $this->author,
    ]
}
```